# How to Update dataset and backend sql table from Gridview data without for loop?

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In ASP.NET i have GridView as

```
    <asp:GridView ID="GV" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtName" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Name") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailId" HeaderText="Email" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
 <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Update Changes to Dataset" />
```

here is my code behind to bind the data on page load

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Dim str As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("DBCon").ConnectionString
        Dim Conn As New SqlConnection(str)
        Conn.Open()
        Dim qry As String = "SELECT Name,EmailId FROM dbo.Employee"
        Dim adp As New SqlDataAdapter(qry, Conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        adp.Fill(ds)

        GV.DataSource = ds
        GV.DataBind()


    End If
End Sub
```

Now in my Gridview i have bind Name to Textbox and those textboxes are editable for client

**I have plenty of records to show on gridview**
Now what i want is that on a click of submit button updated data to be appeared in a dataset **without using any kind of for loop**
And i **also want the updated data to be reflected at backend Employee table**
Suggest if you have any tricks

Comment: So you want to update all rows in the database without a loop. Are you kidding? You need to loop the `GridViewRows` and use `row.FindControl("txtName")` to get a reference to your TextBox. Then you can update each row in the database.

Comment: As i mentioned i have plenty of records to process hence looping i don't think i right choice

Comment: No matter what you do, any fancy code we provide that looks like it isn't going to loop is always going to loop internally anyway.

Comment: Yes, but how many rows are you showing in the grid without paging, 10,100 or even 1000? However, even with 10000 it would be efficient enough to loop all rows and update the database. What is the alternative? You could update as soon as the user leaves the textbox(as in a winforms app). But that's not a good idea.  The real question is if you need to show the user so many rows at all.